Convert $z$ = $1 - \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ to polar form
I was given this question for homework.
When it came time to solve $\theta$ I eventually got $\theta= \arctan$($\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}$)
Where do I go from here since I can't see what to do with $\arctan(\cot(\frac{x}{2}))$.

what mean : "convert $z=...$ ??

@Surb sorry, I have made the correction. It is asking for polar form

From How to ask a good question: "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Just see this Identity

@LuckyChouhan thank you. I get it now

Hint: $z=2i\sin\frac12x(\cos\frac12x-i\sin\frac12x)$.

We have a well-known identity:
$\cot\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$
Obviously, $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\geq0$.
When $1-\cos x=0\ (\text{i.e., }x=2n\pi,\,n\in\mathbb{Z})$,  $\sin x=0$ and the argument, $\arg(z)$ is undefined.
When $1-\cos x\neq0$, the principal value of the argument:
$\operatorname{Arg}(z)=\operatorname{atan2}\left(\sin x,\, 1-\cos x\right)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\right)=\arctan\left(\cot\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right)$

For $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$, we can express it using floor function as follows:
$\theta_1=\operatorname{Arg}(z)_{(-\pi,\pi]}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x-2\pi\cdot\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right)=\dfrac{\pi-x}{2}+\pi\cdot\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2\pi}\right\rfloor$

If one defines the range of the principal value as being in the closed-open interval, i.e. $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then
$\theta_2=\operatorname{Arg}(z)_{[0,2\pi)}=\theta_1+2\pi\cdot\dfrac{1-\operatorname{sgn}(\theta_1)}{2}=\theta_1+\pi(1-\operatorname{sgn}(\theta_1))$


The absolute value of $z$ is given by:
$r=|z|=\sqrt{(1-\cos x)^2+\sin^2x}=2\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right|$
Note: In general, one can rigorously define the principal value of the argument as follows:

$\operatorname{Arg}(x + iy) = \operatorname{atan2}(y,\, x) =
\begin{cases}
  \arctan\left(\frac y x\right)       &\text{if } x > 0, \\[5mu]
  \arctan\left(\frac y x\right) + \pi &\text{if } x < 0 \text{ and } y \ge 0, \\[5mu]
  \arctan\left(\frac y x\right) - \pi &\text{if } x < 0 \text{ and } y < 0, \\[5mu]
  +\frac{\pi}{2}   &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y > 0, \\[5mu]
  -\frac{\pi}{2}   &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y < 0, \\[5mu]
  \text{undefined} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y = 0.
\end{cases}$

PS: The functions $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ are the 2-argument arctangent function and sign/signum function respectively.

Thank you for your response. It is very detailed. I did notice that the worked solutions my instructor provided simply consider arctan(cot $\frac{x}{2})$ = arctan(tan $\frac{x}{2})$. Is this incorrect or is it an alternative solution? My opinion is that it is incorrect

Do you mean $\arctan\left(\cot\frac{x}{2}\right)=\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$? It is one of the possible values of the argument which might not give a principal value in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi)$ for all values of $x$. The set of all possible values of the argument can be written in terms of its principal value $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ as: $\arg(z) = {\operatorname{Arg}(z) + 2\pi n \mid n \in \mathbb Z}$.

No, I meant to say arctan(cot$\frac{x}{2}$) = arctan(tan$\frac{x}{2}$) because that is what my professor said. I am assuming that what he said was a mistake and he meant what you just said

That's incorrect.

I thought so. Thank you
